# How can I use jQuery methods on elements accessed by brackets notation?

Tags: jquery, object, methods

Elements from jQuery object can be accessed by bracket notation, like so: `$('div')[0]`
But in this case jQuery methods cannot be used.

Any other way to access certain elements or use jQuery methods?

Comment: The array accessor is used to get the underlying DOM element from the jQuery object. Why are you doing that if you want to apply jQuery methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the first jQuery object in a collection, use jQuery's `eq()` method:

```
$collection.eq(0);
```

You can also use the `:eq()` selector when creating the collection in the first place:

```
var $collection = $('div:eq(0)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a jQuery object again:

```
var element = $('div')[0]; // DOM element
var $element = $(element); // jQuery object
```

Better yet, just use a narrower selector in the first place:

```
var $element = $('div:eq(0)');
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/